# Howto further constrain an existing type class in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, typeclass

Is there a way to further constrain the context of an existing type class?

For example, the type class `Functor`:

```
class Functor f where
    fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

This class definition does not enforce `a` or `b` to be an element of `Show`. Also this type class is a class that is included by myself, so i can't influence the classes definition. Is it still possible, to later allow only that `a`'s and that `b`'s, that are member of `Show`?

Comment: It would be quite interesting to hear why you want to have artificial constraints that are not justified by the code. It may be that there are misunderstandings that could be resolved.

Comment: Constraints are usually put on functions, not on data/typeclasses. The reason is : you'll never know what you need. Let's say you use `ShowFunctor` from Daniel answer. You can't make it an applicative (and therefore a Monad) because applicatives needs to be able to wrap functions and function doesn't have a show instance.

Comment: As other answers already pointed to, it is not possible. But fwiw, if it's your own type class, and you would want to defer that decision of further constraining it, I have made a little attempt here: https://discourse.haskell.org/t/defer-extra-constraints-in-later-integration-stage-of-the-development/4713

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not directly. The class's definition cannot be changed without changing the source and recompiling. In the case of classes defined in the standard libraries, that would cause much breaking of code, so is not a realistic option.

You can however, wrap the class and add your desired constraints,

```
class Functor f => ShowFunctor f where
    smap :: (Show a, Show b) => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
    smap f = fmap f
```

and then use that class instead of the original.

But maybe you don't need the additional class and for your applications it is sufficient to define `smap` at the top level and simply use that instead of `fmap`,

```
smap :: (Functor f, Show a, Show b) => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
smap = fmap
```

Comment: Probably `ShowFunctor` should not be a subclass of `Functor` since it is adding a pre-condition.  Every `Functor` is a `ShowFunctor` but not necessarily vice versa.

Comment: If the point is to further restrict an existing class, I think making it a subclass is the right way. Unless I completely misunderstood and the OP wants that instances of `ShowFunctor` can only wrap types belonging to `Show` (`data ShowList a where ShowList :: Show a => [a] -> ShowList a; instance ShowFunctor ShowList where smap f (ShowList xs) = ShowList (fmap f xs)`), but that can't be enforced by the class (at least not in H2010).

Comment: @frosch03 Can you clarify whether I misunderstood?

Comment: @DanielFischer, you got it right, and i also believe that in this case it makes sense to make `ShowFunctor` a subclass of `Functor` although i also understand @PhilipJF's remark

Comment: I guess it depends on the use case.  I generally think subclassing should follow OOP design principles (at least LSP style thinking) when possible.  After all, Haskell classes are just OO classes except they dont have state, take functions in their constructor, and are automatically passed instead of being treated as first class values.

Comment: Constraint kinds!  They allow handling situations like these more generally! http://blog.omega-prime.co.uk/?p=127

Comment: @PhilipJF, three years late, but no, Haskell classes are not really much like OO classes. Classes like `Monoid`, `Eq`, and perhaps most obviously `Read` don't really fit an OO model at all.

Comment: @dfeuer Yes they do...or at least they do after a dictionary passing translation.

Comment: @PhilipJF, that sounds a bit like a stretch to me. The "subtyping" at that level is purely structural, which isn't quite the way OO tends to work.

Comment: Just note that `ShowFunctor` can't be made applicative if needed.

Comment: @dfeuer the subtyping of haskell classes is nominal.  So, you only need nominal subtyping of dictionaries and the standard "structural" rule for functions (which you get if you have co/contra variance and think of functions as a generic...so in any reasonably OOP language) is all you need to type the dictionary passing transform.

The subtyping one sees in something like control.lens is technically nominal also since it haskell subclassing underneath.  It is just CPSed so inverted from what you are used to (open above instead of open below).

Answer (score 2):

You cant do that without breaking things (currently).

You have a couple of options

1. define your own restricted `Functor` class
2. dont worry about defining a class and just define a function that does what you want
3. use the [RMonad package](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/rmonad/0.4.1/doc/html/Control-RMonad.html)
4. cheat

Actually, we now know how to allow instances to add constraints, so perhaps one day this wont be so bad, see [Subcategories in Haskell](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~dao29/drafts/subcategories-in-haskell-dorchard11.pdf) for a paper that deals with almost exactly this issue.  The syntax in that paper is a little different than what currently works in GHC, but basically we would like to redefine the `Functor` class to look like

```
class Functor f where
   type SubCat f :: * -> Constraint -- associated constraint
   type SubCat f = () -- default definition
   fmap :: (SubCat f a, SubCat f b) => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```